# Plotting multidimensional array python

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

To the other plotting geniuses out there. I cannot find a decent document that can explain in simple way how to plot a multidimensional array in python.

The array is: (200,252): `total.reshape(self.sims, self.steps)` Hence this is dynamic as well. Sims is simulations and steps are days 252.

The data is posted here: [ExcelResult&Graph](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlgM5yDgNBrMkxcCAUJoDBeEIchy)

Just like in the attached excel, I want to create the same graph in python.

Comment: Assuming `total` is a Numpy ndarray: `plt.plot(total.T)`.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot

Answer (score 0):

Since each line in one simulation, it would simply be

```
for line in my_array:
    plt.plot(line)
plt.show()
```